# SublimeText2 RubyTest "Verify Ruby Syntax" triggers UTF-8 error

Tags: ruby, utf-8, sublimetext2, ruby-test

I am using rvm and ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OS 10.7.5.

I'd like to be able to use Sublime Text 2 RubyTest package to verify my Ruby syntax.

However, when I attempt to run `Tools -> RubyTest -> Verify Ruby Syntax` on any ruby file (`test.rb` below) the following error shows up in the RubyTest console:

> /Users/jladieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby:1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)

My `test.rb` file contents is very simple:

```ruby
class Test
  def hello
    puts "Hello world"
  end
end
```

My `RubyTest.sublime_settings` file is as follows:

```json
{
  "erb_verify_command": "erb -xT - {file_name} | ruby -c",
  "ruby_verify_command": "ruby -c {file_name}",

  "run_ruby_unit_command": "bundle exec ruby -Itest {relative_path}",
  "run_single_ruby_unit_command": "bundle exec ruby -Itest {relative_path} -n '{test_name}'",

  "run_cucumber_command": "zeus cucumber {relative_path} --no-color",
  "run_single_cucumber_command": "zeus cucumber {relative_path}:{line_number} --no-color",

  "run_rspec_command": "zeus rspec {relative_path}",
  "run_single_rspec_command": "zeus rspec {relative_path}:{line_number}",

  "ruby_unit_folder": "test",
  "ruby_cucumber_folder": "features",
  "ruby_rspec_folder": "spec",

  "check_for_rbenv": false,
  "check_for_rvm": true,

  "ruby_use_scratch" : false,
  "save_on_run": true,
  "ignored_directories": [".git", "vendor", "tmp"],

  "hide_panel": false,

  "before_callback": "",
  "after_callback": ""
}
```

Running the following command at the command line works to validate my syntax:

```
$ ruby -c test.rb 
  Syntax OK
```

Finally, I've tried a number of of approaches to fixing the US-ASCII issue to no avail:

- Adding `-ku` flag to the verify command in the RubyTest settings
- `export RUBYOPT=-Ku` in my `.bash_profile` before opening sublime
- `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8`in my bash profile before opening sublime

Anyone able to get this to work using a similar setup?

Note: found an answer (see below), but interested if anyone finds a better solution, thanks!

Comment: You could try to use `{relative_path}` instead of `{file_name}`?

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the suggestion -- I tried that out and now instead of printing anything to the RubyTest console, nothing happens at all (console doesn't even show up), so not sure that's the trick.

Comment: Actually `{file_name}` should [work](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests#settings-1). You could try setting the rvm detection, but that's just a wild guess.

Comment: I meant the `"check_for_rvm": true` setting, but you already applied it.

Comment: Strangest thing, I was getting this error until I added bundle exec ruby which you have above. Now my tests run normally. However, when I verify syntax I now get ruby: No such file or directory -- foobar.rb (LoadError), when I add bundle exec ruby to the verify command. I think it's working but can't find the file now?

Comment: Changing file_name to relative path in the verify_command line doesn't display anything in the test console, but in the regular console it throws: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 362, in run_
  File "./run_ruby_test.py", line 315, in run
  File "./run_ruby_test.py", line 205, in verify_syntax_command
  File "./run_ruby_test.py", line 113, in <lambda>
KeyError: u'relative_path'

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for the idea to use the regular console of Sublime.  I checked out what was printing there, which was this: `Running /Users/jladieu/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby -S ruby -c test.rb`, it turns out when I run that from the command line I get the same error, which tells me this has nothing to do with Sublime and everything to do with rvm-auto-ruby!  Will post back once I know more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On further investigation based on feedback from Aaron and Thomas, changing the `ruby_verify_command` from `ruby -c {file_name}` to just `-c {file_name}` works.

The reason for this is using `check_for_rvm: true` causes the command that gets run to be:

```
$ /Users/jladieu/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby ruby -c test.rb
/Users/jladieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby:1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
```

Setting `ruby_verify_command` to omit `ruby` correctly results in the following command to be run:

```
$ /Users/jladieu/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby -S -c test.rb
Syntax OK
```